# Amplify Jest configuration

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, aws-amplify, ts-jest

I need to setup build pipeline in AWS amplify for create react app.I couldn't find code snippet to add unit test that uses Jest with React testing library and typescript. Can you please share the amplify.yml that have jest unit test. I have tried below

```
version: 1
frontend:
    phases:
        preBuild:
            commands: ['npm ci']
        build:
            commands: 'npm run test' && 'npm run build'
    artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
            - '**/*'
    cache:
        paths:
            - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

Comment: The documentation have a section for e2e tests: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/running-tests.html
What's wrong with the command `npm run test` and map this command to jest?

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I have already checked the documentation that explains only e2e tests. My above npm run test command not executing the build stage and also not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

To add Jest you should first make sure it's installed and listed in your package.json file.

In the root of your project:

> npm install jest --save-dev

You should also add this to package.json:

"scripts": {
"test": "jest"
},

Then run Jest locally by running

> npm run test

If that works you just need to ensure that jest is available in your build environment.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Your-app-name",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you some!